# Webpack Config Issue, blank page in browser

Tags: reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I am working with reactjs and using webpack. After running command "npm start". I am getting blank page when running http:localhost:8080/ in browser. Can anyone help me to solve the issue.

Below is my webpack.config.js file :

```
module.exports = {
  entry: [
    './src/index.js'
  ],
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: ['babel-loader'],
      },{
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: ['babel-loader', 'eslint-loader']
      },{
        test: /\.css$/,
        //include: path.resolve(__dirname, '/src'),
        loaders: ["style-loader","css-loader"]
      },{
          test: /\.(eot|svg|ttf|woff|woff2)$/,
          //loader: 'file?name=public/fonts/[name].[ext]'
          use: [{
              loader: 'file-loader',
              options: {
                  name: '[name].[ext]',
                  outputPath: 'fonts/'
              }
          }]
      },{
        test: /\.(png|jpg|gif)$/,
        use: ['file-loader']
      }

    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['*', '.js', '.jsx']
  },  
  output: {
    path: __dirname + '/dist',
    publicPath: '/',
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  output: {
      path: __dirname + "/public/",
      filename: "bundle.js",
      chunkFilename: '[name].js'
  },  
  devServer: {
    contentBase: __dirname + "/public/",
    port: 8080
  }
};
```

My directory structure is as below :

```
- node_modules/
- public/
-- images/
-- favicon.ico
-- index.html
-- manifest.json
- src/
-- components/
-- css/
-- data/
-- fonts/
-- images/
-- js/
-- index.js
- .babelrc
- .eslintrc
- .package.json
- test.md
- webpack.config.js
```

I am working with reactjs and using webpack. After running command "npm start". I am getting blank page when running http:localhost:8080/ in browser. Can anyone help me to solve the issue?

Comment: Can you share your browser's console screen?

Comment: Is `http:localhost:8080` a typo in your question? It should be `http://localhost:8080`

Comment: you got two `output` fields in config